# How can I replicate this with css?

Tags: html, css

So I was playing around with some CSS, and wanted to give my titles a specific style. What I was thinking about was something like the image I made here:

[image: Example image]

I tried to google for people who wanted the same, but I couldn't really find what I was looking for.

This is what I have so far:

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  font-size:40px;
  height:40px;
  width:400px;
}
.test>span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  color: #31FF5A;
}
.test>.top{
  z-index:2;
  top:0;
}
.test>.bottom{
  color: black;
  height: 100%;
  z-index:1;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <span class="top">TEXT</span>
  <span class="bottom">TEXT</span>
</div>
```

Any one of you who can help me out? Or atleast in the right direction :P

Thanks!

Comment: I am very unsure you can do this with CSS alone. A cut-through SVG image and smartCSS background could solve the issue though

Answer (score 1):

Use border radius property.

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  font-size:40px;
  height:40px;
  width:400px;
}
.test>span {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 60%; */
    color: #31FF5A;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 90%;
}
.test>.top{
  z-index:2;
  top:0;
}
.test>.bottom {
    color: black;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 346%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <span class="top">TEXT</span>
  <span class="bottom">TEXT</span>
</div>
```